# Is it possible to import custom source files into Kubeflow components?

Tags: kubeflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I know that Kubeflow only modifies the container with the specified libraries to be installed. But I want to use my custom module in the training Component section of the pipeline.

So let me clarify my case; I'm deploying a GCP Vertex AI pipeline which exists of preprocessing and training  steps. And there is also custom library that I created using some libraries like scikit. My main issue is that I want to re-use that library objects within my training step which looks like;

````
    packages_to_install = [
        "pandas",
        "sklearn",
        "mycustomlibrary?"
    ],
)
def train_xgb_model(
    dataset: Input[Dataset],
    model_artifact: Output[Model]
):
    
    from MyCustomLibrary import XGBClassifier
    import pandas as pd
    
    data = pd.read_csv(dataset.path)

    model = XGBClassifier(
        objective="binary:logistic"
    )
    model.fit(
        data.drop(columns=["target"]),
        data.target,
    )

    score = model.score(
        data.drop(columns=["target"]),
        data.target,
    )

    model_artifact.metadata["train_score"] = float(score)
    model_artifact.metadata["framework"] = "XGBoost"
    
    model.save_model(model_artifact.path)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to bake your custom module into a custom container image. Then you can use your customer image for the component as:

```py
@component(
    base_image='gcr.io/my-custom-image',
    packages_to_intall = [
        "pandas",
        "sklearn",
    ],
)
def train_xgb_model(...):
    ...
```

In fact if you go this route, you might want to bake `pandas` and `sklearn` into your custom container as well.

Alternatives include hosting your `mycustomlibrary` somewhere on the internet, it can be a GitHub repo for instance. And then you can install it as follows:

```py
@component(
    packages_to_intall = [
        "pandas",
        "sklearn",
        "git+https://my-repo/mycustomlibrary.git",
    ],
)
def train_xgb_model(...):
    ...
```

Note that what specified in `packages_to_install` is passed to `pip install` command. And `pip` allows installing from various sources. For example:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs